# Bash - while loop syntax error

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm new to bash scripting, and atm I'm trying to learn it.

When I run this bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
./pokecli.py
echo ">pokecli exited... restarting...";
sleep 5;
done;
```

I receive this error:

```
opt/PokemonGo-Bot# ./start.sh                         ./start.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token     `done'
./start.sh: line 6: `done;'
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I can't reproduce this in any POSIX shell. Is there more to your script, or does your script have DOS line endings? (It doesn't seem likely, but it's hard to predict sometimes what errors such endings will produce.)

Comment: Also can't reproduce.  What bash are you using?  Here's a random suggestion: you don't need semicolons at line endings in bash.  Maybe get rid of the semicolon after `done` and see if that helps.

Comment: Can reproduce this. Can you show me the result of following command
cat pokecli.py

Comment: I can't reproduce it either.  Comment out the ./pokecli.py call and see if it works.

Comment: Probably carriage returns at the end of the lines.

Comment: @AndroidGL did you fix your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have semicolons where it's not needed.  Also, you should start indenting nested commands and get your do on the same line as the while for readability.  In addition, "while true" can be dangerous, and a "while sleep" is better.

```
#!/bin/bash
while sleep 5; do
   ./pokecli.py
   echo ">pokecli exited... restarting..."
done
```

However, that being said-- none of that will cause an error.  Most likely you have either typo'd your `do`, commented it out, or have (most likely) a Windows (or other special) character prior to the "do", like a ^M or such.  The `dos2unix` command might help, or run this.

`tr -cd '[:graph:]\n\t ' <start.sh >file.tmp && mv file.tmp start.sh`

You'll have to `chmod +x` the script again.

Answer (score -2):

The correct syntax is

7.3 While sample

```
      #!/bin/bash 
     COUNTER=0
     while [  $COUNTER -lt 10 ]; do
         echo The counter is $COUNTER
         let COUNTER=COUNTER+1 
     done
```

So you should change to

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
  ./pokecli.py
  echo ">pokecli exited... restarting...";
  sleep 5;
done
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with putting `do` on the following line; either a semi-colon or a `;` will terminate the command that precedes it. The other semi-colons are redundant but harmless.